# hydrodynamic thickness of polymer vs. concentration of electrolyte?

Tags: polymers, adsorption, colloids

I've measured the hydrodynamic thickness of a NaPSS layer on polystyrene latex and plotted it against the concentration of the supporting electrolyte, NaCl.
My graph shows a general decrease in thickness with some fluctuations at earlier concentrations. I thought that thickness would increase with concentration due to more charge screening. Can anyone help explain these results?
[image: thickness vs. concentration]

Comment: Osmotic pressure?